# If Else Statement Not Triggering Correctly

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, if-statement

Ok, the following code I'm reading in a text file and searching for a specific string in a line. If the string is found, I don't want to do anything and if it's not found, I want to do something else. Right now I have a msgbox for each condition.

The problem I have, is when string is not found, it's not triggering the msgbox. The other msgbox triggers when the string is found though.

Any ideas?

```
    Dim logfile() As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Temp\Transfer_Log.txt")
    Dim searchstring As String = "Test_" + DateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".csv"

    For Each line As String In Filter(logfile, searchstring)
        If line.Contains("Test_" + DateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".csv") Then
            MsgBox("Do Nothing") 'THIS WORKS
        Else
            MsgBox("Append") 'THIS DOES NOT WORK
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Did you consider that you might not have _any_ matching lines, in particular after calling `Filter`? Can you explain what `Filter` does?

Comment: My understanding, which I assume is probably wrong, was to filter out the specific string I was checking for...apparently not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm interpreting your code correcty, `Filter` is a filtering funciton that is returing all lines that match the text `"Test_" + DateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".csv"`. Then you are looping through each line and again comparing it to see if it matches `"Test_" + DateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".csv"`. So your second message box will never be called, ever. I would suggest this,

```
 IF Filter(logFile, searchstring).Count > 0 Then 
      MsgBox("Do Nothing")
 Else
      MsgBox("Append")
 EndIf
```

According to the question, you want to know if the string exists in the file or not, and this will tell you if it does or not.